# Prove or disprove that $a_{n}=\int_{2019}^{n+2019}\frac{\sin{x}}{x\ln{x}}dx$ has a limit

Tags: integration

Let $n$ be postive integer. If we take
$$a_{n}=\int_{2019}^{n+2019}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x\ln{x}}dx$$
how can I prove or disprove that the sequence
$\{a_{n}\}_{n\ge 1}$ has a limit?

It seem I must use this well known: $|\sin{x}|\le 1$ but I can't go on.

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By an integration by parts, you have
$$a_n = \left[- \frac{\cos(x)}{x\ln(x)} \right]_{2019}^{2019+n} - \int_{2019}^{2019+n} \cos(x)\frac{\ln(x)+1}{x^2 \ln^2(x)} \,dx$$

The first term has a finite limit, and the second one also, since for every $x \geq 2019$,
$$\left| \cos(x)\frac{\ln(x)+1}{x^2 \ln^2(x)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$

which is integrable on $[2019, +\infty)$.

So $(a_n)$ has a finite limit.

Comment: It's very  nice!+1